# How to run QEMU without TCG and without KVM

Tags: qemu, kvm

I'm trying to shut down a virtual core while my QEMU Virtual Machine is running.

For that purpose, I need to use the function `qemu_cpu_kick()` which is found at cpus.c:

```
void qemu_cpu_kick(CPUState *cpu)
{
    qemu_cond_broadcast(cpu->halt_cond);
    if (!tcg_enabled() && !cpu->thread_kicked) {
            qemu_cpu_kick_thread(cpu);
            cpu->thread_kicked = true;
    }
}
```

It works well - only if I enable KVM.
However, **I need to have KVM disabled**, and once I disable KVM - the `tcg_enabled()` function returns true, and the cpu doesn't shut down.

Is it possible to disable TCG?

I didn't find any knob regarding TCG; `--disable-tcg`, as well as other trials, do not work. 
I tried to reconfigure my compilation with `--disable-tcg-interpreter`, but still nothing changes.

So, how can I disable TCG ? Or, alternatively - is there a better way to shut down a virtual cpu?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, as I understood, running QEMU without KVM forces QEMU to use the Tiny Code Generator (TCG) instead of KVM. So, running QEMU without KVM and without TCG is simply not possible!